# Can I use target="_blank" In Markdown file?

Tags: github-flavored-markdown

I have build my project and I create one markdown file (README.md). I create this for describe my project but I use my project preview link with using target blank but if I click preview link then don't open output on the new tab.
So, I want know can you have solution of this problem? .

I want to solve this problem but I don't understand and I searching solution of this problem but if I solve this problem then share with you but if you know solution then share with me

Answer (score 0):

You can put raw HTML into Markdown files. So just use an anchor tag;

```html
<a target="_blank" href="your link here">Click me!</a>
```

[Read more](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax)